# Has Leta Lestrange been mentioned in canon before?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

Has Leta Lestrange been mentioned at all outside of the *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* movie?

Comment: Side-note: People are always relating Leta Lestrange to the infamous Bellatrix Lestrange, but they might be interested in being reminded that Bellatrix is originally a Black (i.e. Sirius Black), as well as her sister, Narcissa Malfoy (nee Narcissa Black).

Comment: @GhotiandChips Who knows, maybe Leta Lestrange will end up marrying someone from the Black family and being Bellatrix's ancestor anyway!

Comment: @Randal'Thor Bellatrix goes from being a Black to a Lestrange by marrying Rodolphus Lestrange

Comment: @GhotiandChips Yes, I know. I meant that if Leta Lestrange marries a Black, she could still be the ancestor of Bellatrix Black.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I understand what you meant :) I only meant (with my last comment) to bring up the relationship, in light of your own comment, to indicate the possibility of inbreeding such a reveal would imply (not that someone as deranged as Bella makes that far-fetched). Might be weird though, for Rowling to go full G.R.R.M and touch on incest like that :P

Comment: Leta is grandmother of Bellatrix's husband.

Comment: I'll check my family tree! ;)

Comment: @GhotiandChips Bellatrix is perfectly sane, thank you very much! :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No.

[This article in Bustle](https://www.bustle.com/articles/196626-is-leta-lestrange-in-the-harry-potter-books-newts-mysterious-ex-is-a-brand-new-character), entitled "*Is Leta Lestrange In The Harry Potter Books? Newt's Mysterious Ex Is A Brand New Character*", makes this very clear:

> In Fantastic Beasts, the Lestrange family doesn't directly appear, but it is teased that Newt Scamander had a close relationship with one Leta Lestrange (played by Zoe Kravitz). If you're like me, the second you heard that name you thought to yourself, "I don't remember a Leta Lestrange." And if you then panicked about possibly forgetting a Harry Potter detail, don't worry: **[Leta Lestrange is not in the Harry Potter books](https://www.bustle.com/articles/194563-who-is-leda-lestrange-fantastic-beasts-is-only-the-start-for-the-new-character-says-director)**.
>
> [...]
>
> Given the fact that **Leta is a new character to the Harry Potter world**, there isn't much we can learn about her from the Harry Potter series, but we will be learning a whole lot more in the planned Fantastic Beasts sequel. "Leta comes into the second movie," [director David Yates said at a recent press junket for *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*](https://www.bustle.com/articles/194563-who-is-leda-lestrange-fantastic-beasts-is-only-the-start-for-the-new-character-says-director).
>
> <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Both of the links in the quoted text above are to a second Bustle article, which confirms that Leda [sic] Lestrange is a brand-new character created for the *Fantastic Beasts* films.

Comment: What is the purpose of quoting the Bustle article? Do they have any insider information?

Answer (score 4):

### No

JK Rowling was asked a similar question on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/801727313545166849):

> **who is leta lestrange plz i can't live like this**
>   **J.K. Rowling**: *Next movie.*

This would seem to imply that she hadn't been previously mentioned.

Additionally, I can confirm (by means of doing computer searches on Rowling's previous writings) that no character with that name has appeared.